# Form to send email using PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have a form in my HTML/CSS and I need to give it an action. I want it to email me with the fields filled out with the results. I heard this is possible using PHP but I am quite a PHP beginner.

Here is my html

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXpXZa

I have found the below PHP but need to know how to add one for the Twitter username field

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
$recipient="your@email.address";
$subject="Form to email message";
$sender=$_POST["sender"];
$senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
$message=$_POST["message"];

$mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$message";

mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

$thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
//give a name attribute for all control in the html page e.g name="twitter" and use the bellow modified code

if($_POST["submit"]) {
$recipient="your@email.address";
$subject="Form to email message";
$sender=$_POST["sender"];
$twittername = $_POST['twitter']
$senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
$message=$_POST["message"];

$mailBody="Name: $sender \n $twitter \nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$message";

mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

$thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Where does the

    $thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";

appear ?

Comment: You can add it to mailBody.= $thankYou and then call mail(..) function it actually depends on you whether you want to show the thank you message from the webpage or to the email body

Comment: It works now and it is sending me an email, however when i click submit on the form, I don't want a new page to open. It opens my .php file. How can I just have a small javascript popup or something saying thank you when the button is clicked?

Comment: See here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610455/how-do-you-display-a-javascript-alert-from-php
 and if your work goes well please accept my answer